# UITableView+.plist+UINavigationController issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

As my first app I am trying to master simple Navigation Based numismatic collection app.

There's some trouble with indexes in my array filled from .plist. Plist has 191 records; the ordinary list of countries -> item 0 - String - Albania ... item 190 - String - Vanuatu.

I read these records into my temporary array to populate UITableView.

```
NSString *countriesFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"plist"];
countries=[[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:countriesFile];
```

This table view has sections -> continents.

[image: RootViewController of my app]

Well, my problem is:

**When pushing to another nib, it should read the name of country and show it in header and label. So it does, but only for european countries. If I tap some other continent's country, I see some european country. Please see screenshots**

Tapping on european country -> Belgium, shows right.

[image]

Moving to african section:

[image]

Taping on Angola and getting Austria.

[image]

So, Angola's index - 92. Austria - 1. But Austria and Angola are both second cell in their native section.

Where's the problem and what would it be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `-(void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath` to tell when you have clicked on an item in the list?
Also, are you using `[indexPath row]` (or `indexPath.row`) to figure out the index of the row you tapped on?

What the `row` property returns is the row index within the current section.  It does NOT return the absolute row index for the entire table.  Because of this, it does not matter if you click on the index two item in the first section or the index two item in the second section, `row` will return 2 in both of those cases.

An idea would be to change the .plist file a bit.  Instead of it only having one long array of countries, have a parent array that represents the continents.  Then the object for each index in this continent array, have another array that will hold the list of countries in there.

```
-(void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section=[indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row=[indexPath row];
    NSString* countryName=[[plistArray objectAtIndex: section] objectAtIndex: row];
    //rest of code...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean to change the .plist? How? Array -> Collection?

Comment: Well my method now looks like: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section=[indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row=[indexPath row];
    NSString* countryName=[[countries objectAtIndex: section] objectAtIndex: row];
    
    SelectedCountry *selectedCountry = [[SelectedCountry alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectedCountry" bundle:nil];
    selectedCountry.selectedCountry = [countryName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectedCountry animated:YES];
    [selectedCountry release];
}

Comment: It says now: 'NSString may not respond to 'objectAtIndex''. Should I change var type? To what?

Comment: Guys ;-(, Steve Jobs has passed away. The saddest new of this year. At least for me. R.I.P

Comment: @Nathan For an example .plist file:  http://www.kendallp.net/public/files/stack.plist .  Check for a (sort of) example of what your method should look like:  http://www.kendallp.net/public/files/stack.m .  As stated in the comment, you will need to modify that method so that it can read the .plist file as I have formatted it above.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not taking into account the section value of indexPath. An indexPath has two parts, a section and a row. In tables that have a single section you usually just read the row value. In your case it looks like you have a grouped table so you need to read both indexPath.section and indexPath.row for the data location.

Comment: Each continent is a section. So section 0 is Europe. Look at any of the UITable documentation.